# Can't create a file in Azure App Service file system

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, filesystems, azure-appservice, azure-app-service-envrmnt

I am trying to create a file in azure app service file system. My app is a .NET c# app. Doing it like this currently:

```
var tempDirectoryPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
string filePath = tempDirectoryPath + "myfile.xlsx";
```

Doesn't work for some reason... But it also doesn't give me any error in the logs. Does anyone know why it doesn't create my file?

Comment: Try creating the file under %HOME% (C:\home | D:\home) https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Understanding-the-Azure-App-Service-file-system#persisted-files

Answer (score 0):

Could you please confirm your privileges,
Try using below command:

```
var tempDirectoryPath = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("TEMP");
var filePath = Path.Combine(tempDirectoryPath, Request.Files["file"]);
```